# pointStart and pointInterval does not work

Tags: highcharts

I adjusted pointStart and pointInterval within chart-options:

```
        xAxis: {
                   type: 'datetime',
                   ordinal: true,
                   tickInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minute intervals
                   minTickInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minute intervals
               },

               plotOptions: {
                   series: {
                     pointStart: "2017-11-25T00:00:00",
                     pointInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minute intervals

               }},
```

When plotting, the chart is shown but with wrong x-time-axis. Start and end date is shown as "1970-01-01" and the interval between each tick is 1 ms. What is wrong?

Comment: Please share a working example of your code illustrating this issue.

Comment: I updated the code to a working example. Everything works fine but x-axis time-scaling is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that time needs to be given in milliseconds since 1970. Since you give 1005, it adds that to 1970, not from your pointstart. See https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.column.pointStart

Comment: Has highchart built-in functions to transform such kind of patterns? For example a "dateConverter"?

Comment: Highcharts does not have, but you can use javascript date parsing. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

Time needs to be given in milliseconds since 1970.